# Summation of weighted squares of binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, summation, contest-math

Show that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \left[ \frac{n-2k}{n} {n\choose k}\right]^2=\frac{2}{n}{2n-2 \choose n-1}.$$

Comment: You mention contest-math. From what contest did this come? What have you tried?

Comment: A translation in terms of random walks simplifies the computations, partly.

Comment: I always considered the contest-math tag to be for problems in the contest style, not just those from actual contests. Perhaps this is the case here?

Comment: @Did We can do that with the [Chu-Vandermonde identity](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Chu-Vandermonde_Identity) (as shown by robjohn's deleted answer). But a translation in terms of random walks would make the question more interesting for me. What would that be?

Comment: @Potato: I mainly wanted to verify that this was not from an ongoing contest. Once I know that, I will undelete my answer. It would be nice to see what Did was suggesting, too.

Comment: @robjohn Is the default presumption really that all tricky-looking problems are from ongoing contests? In any case, I can verify that this one isn't. It's from Problem Solving Through Problems by Larson.

Comment: @Potato: that it appears in a book doesn't mean that it isn't also in an ongoing contest, but this doesn't seem like a contest problem. However, in addition, this is also a PSQ. I'll wait for a bit more and see if the OP has anything to add.

Comment: @Potato: Thanks for the source of the problem ;-)

Comment: @robjohn ;-) $\textbf{}$

Comment: @julien The LHS times $n^22^{-2n}$ is $E[S_n^2;S_{2n}=0]$, where $(S_k)$ is a standard $\pm1$ random walk. Expanding $S_n^2$, this is $nP[S_{2n}=0]$ (known) plus $n(n-1)\alpha$ with $\alpha=E[X_1X_2;S_{2n}=0]$, where $(X_k)$ are the increments of the random walk. Since $X_1X_2=\pm1$, $\alpha$ is $\frac12P[S_{2n-2}=2]$ (known) minus $\frac12P[S_{2n-2}=0]$ (known). Reducing the three binomial coefficients involved to ${2n-2\choose n-1}$ yields the result, but this last part of the proof, while easy, is not very illuminating nor very random-walk-oriented, which is the reason why I wrote "partly".

Comment: .../... However, somebody cleverer than me might find a way to compute $E[S_n^2;S_{2n}=0]$ using purely probabilistic arguments till the end...

Comment: @Did this random walk thing is pretty new to me, though I do have sort of a dim idea. Any resources for a newb? :)

Comment: @SohamChowdhury [A short one](http://www-math.mit.edu/phase2/UJM/vol1/RMONTE-F.PDF) and a (much) [longer one](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~lawler/srwbook.pdf‎).

Comment: @Did Ok, thanks a lot.

Comment: @julien You are welcome. I now asked this [as a separate question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/443343/).

Comment: @Did the second link 404s.

Comment: @SohamChowdhury Sorry, try [this one](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~lawler/srwbook.pdf).

Answer (score 11):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\frac{n-2k}{n}\binom{n}{k}\right]^2
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\binom{n}{k}-2\binom{n-1}{k-1}\right]^2\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\binom{n-1}{k}-\binom{n-1}{k-1}\right]^2\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-1}{k}^2+\binom{n-1}{k-1}^2-2\binom{n-1}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\\
&=2\binom{2n-2}{n-1}-2\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-1}{k}\binom{n-1}{n-k}\\
&=2\binom{2n-2}{n-1}-2\binom{2n-2}{n}\\
&=2\binom{2n-2}{n-1}-2\frac{n-1}{n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\\
&=\frac2n\binom{2n-2}{n-1}
\end{align}
$$